# Runtime of an easy while loop

Tags: loops, runtime

I have a short question about the runtime of a while loop.
I have the given code:

```
Calculate(int n)  
i = n  
while(i > 0)  
    i = i/2
```

If n is a power of two, how often will the while loop be executed. I am doing revision on something we did at the beginning of the semester and I know it's not hard but I just don't know how the answer. For example if n = 1, the loop would be executed one time, if n = 2, the then loop would be executed 2 times, if n = 4, the loop would be executed 3 times and so on but I am not sure how to formulate that mathematically.

Comment: Hint: In every iteration, you chop off one bit of information from that integer. How many bits are needed to represent your initial number?

Answer (score 1):

A mathematical formula for this will use the [binary logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm):

log2(n) + 1